# Gerar class aleatória com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Opa! Tava precisando que quando a função fosse executada, a class que o `#body` iria receber, fosse randômica entre as existentes. Exemplo:

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#random').click(function(){
                    $('#body').addClass('red');
                });
            });
```

Ao executar a #random escolhe um valor entre ('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow') e aplica no `.addClass`.
Algum deus do JQuery pode me ajudar nessa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa ser um Deus do jQuery para isso :)

Para colocar a cor randomicamente quando a página é carregada basta utiliza isso:

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
var random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % colors.length
var random_color = colors[random_index]

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#random').click(function(){
        $('#body').addClass(random_color);
    });
});
```

Para trocar a classe quando o usuário quiser você precisa colocar alguma forma com que o usuário possa informar isso, tipo um botão.

```
<button id="changeColor"></button>
<script>
    $('#changeColor').click(function(){
        //Como você já criou o array colors antes, você não precisa criar novamente.
        random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % colors.length
        random_color = colors[random_index]
        $(colors).each(function(index, value){
            $('#body').removeClass(value);
        });
        $('#body').addClass(random_color);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Funciona, mas apenas uma vez. No caso, queria que o usuário ficasse trocando de cor quando quisesse. Tem como? ;D Valeu.

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta de modo que possa atender ao que você quer.

Comment: Perfeito! Ficou do jeito que eu queria :D Obrigado!!!

Comment: sempre bom ajudar ;)